# How can i add a specific class to an element when clicking on a div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following list of elements/items:

```
<div class="list-item">
<div class="store-name">Apple</div>
<div class="hotdeal-tag">%</div>
<div class="popup-tip">10% OFF</div>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
<div class="store-name">Microsoft</div>
<div class="hotdeal-tag">%</div>
<div class="popup-tip">10% OFF</div>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
<div class="store-name">Linux</div>
<div class="hotdeal-tag">%</div>
<div class="popup-tip">10% OFF</div>
</div>
```

and i want every time i click on the div with the class "hotdeal-tag" to add a new class ".show-me" on it.
The problem with my code, as it is now, is that when i click the "hotdeal-tag" div it displays all of three "popup-tip" divs. As i 'm new in jquery i can't figure out what i 'm doing wrong.

Here's my code snippet:

```js
$( ".list-item" ).each(function() {
    $('.hotdeal-tag').on("click", function(){
  $('.popup-tip').toggleClass('show-me');
 });
   });
```

```css
.list-item {
  width:80%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding:10px;
  background:#eee;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.store-name {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}

.hotdeal-tag {
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:20px;
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:4px;
  font-weight:bold;
  float:right;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.popup-tip {
  position:absolute;
  right:45px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:11px;
  top:12px;
  padding:3px;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:4px;
  display:none;
}

.show-me {
  display:block!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list-item">
<div class="store-name">Apple</div>
 <div class="hotdeal-tag">%</div>
 <div class="popup-tip">20% OFF</div>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
<div class="store-name">Microsoft</div>
 <div class="hotdeal-tag">%</div>
 <div class="popup-tip">10% OFF</div>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
<div class="store-name">Linux</div>
 <div class="hotdeal-tag">%</div>
 <div class="popup-tip">35% OFF</div>
</div>
```

And here's the **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d3s1gn3r/jkscqb4m/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're querying all .popup-tips with $('.popup-tip'), you can use sibling selector on the clicked div to add class to the .popup-tip you want.

```js
$( ".list-item" ).each(function() {
    $('.hotdeal-tag').on("click", function(){
  $(this).siblings('.popup-tip').toggleClass('show-me');
 });
   });
```

```css
.list-item {
  width:80%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding:10px;
  background:#eee;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.store-name {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
}

.hotdeal-tag {
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:20px;
  background:red;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:4px;
  font-weight:bold;
  float:right;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.popup-tip {
  position:absolute;
  right:45px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:11px;
  top:12px;
  padding:3px;
  background:#fff;
  border-radius:4px;
  display:none;
}

.show-me {
  display:block!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list-item">
<div class="store-name">Apple</div>
 <div class="hotdeal-tag">%</div>
 <div class="popup-tip">20% OFF</div>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
<div class="store-name">Microsoft</div>
 <div class="hotdeal-tag">%</div>
 <div class="popup-tip">10% OFF</div>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
<div class="store-name">Linux</div>
 <div class="hotdeal-tag">%</div>
 <div class="popup-tip">35% OFF</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need each in here, i think try this one.

```
$(function(){
    $('.hotdeal-tag').click(function(event) {
        $(this).next().toggleClass('show-me');
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the outer each.

*This* should be enough.

```
$(".hotdeal-tag").on('click', function () {
     $(this).next(".popup-tip").toggleClass("show-me");
});
```